# getting mouse coordinates correct when zooming the picture

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Im trying to develop script where I can click on image and get the X/Y of the click. This part Ive implemented, the problem Im having occurs when I try to zoom the picture. Subseqent clicks on zoomed picture should return the same coordinates, and thats where I fail to success.

```
 clicked(event) {
    let pos_x = event.offsetX ? (event.offsetX) : event.pageX - document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetLeft;
    let pos_y = event.offsetY ? (event.offsetY) : event.pageY - document.getElementById("pointer_div").offsetTop;

    let offsetLeft = document.getElementById("textLayer").offsetWidth;
    let offsetTop = document.getElementById("textLayer").offsetHeight;
    console.log("zoom " + this.zoom);
    console.log("pozycja x " + event.clientX/this.zoom);
    console.log("pozycja y " + event.clientY/this.zoom);
    console.log("szerokosc elementu " + offsetLeft);
    console.log("wysokosc elementu " + offsetTop);
  }

  zoomView(): void {
    this.zoom = this.zoom + 2.0;
  }
```

this is what ihve wrote. And the template to the component:

```
<pdf-viewer style="position: absolute" id="textLayer" [src]="'http://localhost:8080/get.pdf'"
            [page]="page"
            [original-size]="true"
            style="display: block;"
            [zoom]="[zoom]"
            (click)="clicked($event)"
></pdf-viewer>
```

Answer (score 1):

since Ive found a solution =>

```
 var x = event.pageX - (document.getElementById("textLayer").offsetLeft);
    var y = event.pageY - (document.getElementById("textLayer").offsetTop);
    console.log("zoom " + this.zoom);
    console.log("pozycja x " + x/this.zoom);
    console.log("pozycja y " + y/this.zoom);
    console.log("szerokosc elementu " + offsetLeft);
    console.log("wysokosc elementu " + offsetTop);
    console.log("wysokosc elementussssssssssssss " + offsetTop);
```